# Need help showing username in comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I honestly have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I have associated comments with posts and users.

user.rb

```
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

post.rb

```
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

comment.rb

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
```

Comments controller

```
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:body))
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      # something else
    end
  end
```

Posts view

```
<h2><%= @comment.user.name %></h2>
<p><%= comment.body %></p>
```

What am I doing wrong?
In my controller, I have also tried `@comment.user = current_user.name`
In my posts view, I have also tried `<%= @comment.user.name %>` and `<%= @comment.user %>`

ERROR: I can't remember if this is the same error I got before, but this is the error I'm seeing when I try to create a comment.

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in CommentsController#create

can't write unknown attribute `user_id`

@comment.user = current_user
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong? It's not clear to me from your question what isn't working.

Comment: I added the error message

Comment: Please post the migration of comments

Comment: Is there a `user_id` column on the comments table? Did you check what `current_user` returns in the `create` action? Did you forget to protect the `new` and `create` action for usage by logged in users only?

Answer (score 0):

So from your error message it looks like you might not have your foreign key user_id on the comments table.

You will need to run

rails g migration AddUserToComments user:references

Comment: Error when I try to create a comment: `NoMethodError in Posts#show` `undefinded method for user` `<h2><%= @comment.user.name %></h2>`

Comment: Is there a name column on the user table?

Comment: Yes, `t.string   "name"`

Comment: Simon Knight? Any help?

Comment: Hi, sorry its difficult to diagnose the problem. Did you put a pry into your create controller action and make sure all the lines of code are running correctly?